# Why button itself does not remain visible after click event which is updating label text propertly

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8.1, winjs

Using blank template
My default.html has following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HiThere</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- HelloWorld references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <h1 id="msg" />
    <br />
    <button id="btn">Say Hello</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My default.css

> body { }

here is the default.html

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        WinJS.UI.processAll().done(
            function () {
                var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
                btn.addEventListener("click", btnClick);
            });
    };

    function btnClick(mouseEvent) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerText = "Hello there";
    }
    app.start();
})();
```

Problem is that when I click on button, the text Hello there is displayed but button get disappears. Can someone provide any idea as what I am doing wrong that is causing button to be not shown.

Comment: Why use XML syntax (e.g. `<br />`) in an HTML document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but changing `<h1 id="msg" />` to `<h1 id="msg"></h1>` fixed the problem

Comment: Because `<h1 id="msg" />` is invalid in an HTML document.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was with the markup—don't use XML markup in an HTML document.

When a browser sees:

```
<h1 />
```

it finds only an H1 opening tag (the `/` is meaningless) and will not close the element until it finds a closing tag or matching `</`. If none is found, it will fall back to error correction. Likely (though not certainly) the browser was turing:

```
<h1 id="msg" />
    <br />
    <button id="btn">Say Hello</button>
```

into:

```
<h1 id="msg">
    <br>
    <button id="btn">Say Hello</button>
</h1>
```

So when you replace the [*innerText*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (the W3C compliant equivalent is [*textContent*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent)) the entire content of the H1 is replaced with the supplied text, resulting in:

```
<h1 id="msg">Hello there</h1>
```

It is a common misconception that XML–style markup can or should be used in HTML documents, however that is a fallacy that was created by the aborted attempt to change HTML into XML during the XHTML era. Use HTML markup in an HTML document, save XML for XML documents.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this, value is the text displayed, the type is the type of input.

```
<input id="btn" value="button" type="button">
```

"`<button>` will implicitly submit, which can cause problems if you want to use a button in a form without it submitting. Thus, another reason to use `<input type="button">` (or `<button type="button">`)

Without a type, `button` implicitly receives type of `submit`. It does not matter how many submit buttons or inputs there are in the form, any one of them which is explicitly or implicitly typed as submit, when clicked, will submit the form."

- credit for the quote to Travis J.

You will need to change your javascript getElementById too, to,

```
document.getElementById("btn").value = "Hello there";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately the button still become invisible after button click. I realized that I had a type in             document.getElementById("btn").innerText = "Hello there"; The code is actually document.getElementById("msg").innerText = "Hello there"; that I fixed in my question also. Any other ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The button isn't in a form, so that isn't the issue. It can be prevented from being a submit button by giving it `type="button"`.

Comment: The reply that you posted to your own question is the answer. <br> has to be ended by a </br> tag. see [w3 schools documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) for the correct usage of tags in html